# I thought the order of items of the WHERE clause didn't matter, why does it matter in my code?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This doesn't work:

```
SELECT
    CAST(o.OrderNo AS INT) AS [OrderNo], 
    DATEADD(d, 7, CAST(SUBSTRING(o.User_Memo1, 
    CHARINDEX('Pack',o.User_Memo1)+5, 8) AS DATE)) AS [1 Week After Prod Due],
    o.User_Date1 AS [3 Week Ack Date]  
FROM Orders o 
    JOIN OrderDet od ON o.OrderNo = od.OrderNo
    LEFT JOIN DelTicket d ON o.OrderNo = d.OrderNo
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), o.User_Memo1) IS NOT NULL
    AND o.User_Date1 IS NULL
    AND DATEADD(d, -24, DATEADD(d, 7, CAST(SUBSTRING(o.User_Memo1, 
    CHARINDEX('Pack',o.User_Memo1)+5, 8) AS DATE))) < CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
    AND SUBSTRING(o.User_Memo1, 1, 3) = 'Cut'
GROUP BY o.OrderNo, DATEADD(d, 7, CAST(SUBSTRING(o.User_Memo1, 
CHARINDEX('Pack',o.User_Memo1)+5, 8) AS DATE)), o.User_Date1, o.User_Date2, 
o.User_Number2, d.ShipDate, o.User_Number3
ORDER BY DATEADD(d, 7, CAST(SUBSTRING(o.User_Memo1, 
CHARINDEX('Pack',o.User_Memo1)+5, 8) AS DATE)) DESC;
```

I get this error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.>

If I put this item:

```
    AND DATEADD(d, -24, DATEADD(d, 7, CAST(SUBSTRING(o.User_Memo1, 
CHARINDEX('Pack',o.User_Memo1)+5, 8) AS DATE))) < CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

At the end of the WHERE clause, it runs perfectly as expected.  Items that don't have 'Cut' in User_Memo1 should indeed fail converting.  However, I've read that the order doesn't matter.  So I'm confused??

Edit: Updating with screenshots

[image]

[image]

Comment: You got lucky. The point is that you can't control the sequence that predicates execute. In your case it happens to run in the same sequence as your code. That will not always be the case even with the same table. If the number of rows changes or even things as minor as statistics being different the query engine may process the predicates in a different order next time.

Comment: well, this shouldn't happen....so I think that something else changes between runs of the code

Comment: I agree with Lamak.  Can you post a script that fully reproduces the issue?   If not, I have to doubt that what you say is happening is actually happening.

Comment: I added the screenshots if that helps

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with order by.  It looks like in the first query you have an additional filter that is excluding the suspect data that is having trouble converting in the second query.

Comment: @DanielMarcus op didn't say it has to be with the `ORDER BY` clause, but with the order of filters in the `WHERE`

Comment: If you are using SQL Server 2012 or later, you might consider changing your CAST statements to TRY_CAST. That would keep it running regardless of the order of execution.

Comment: Wow, with TRY_CAST it does indeed work in any order

Comment: Note that `on` is performed before `where`. ([Ref](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/06/sql-server-logical-query-processing-phases-order-of-statement-execution/).) If you move some of the logic, e.g. NULL checks and checking for `'Cut'`, to the `on` clauses you can force some order on the logic. Aside: How does `CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), o.User_Memo1) IS NOT NULL` differ from `o.User_Memo1 is not NULL`?

Comment: [Not the same, but related...](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/203399/70663) I solved this by placing the `JOIN`s in the *best* order and used the [table hint `FORCE ORDER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table) and as [summary](http://www.sqlserver.info/syntax/force-order-query-hint/)

Answer (score 1):

In theory the order does not matter. However, it may happen with complex queries that query optimizer follows a different path and it results in a different execution plan. This is typical for queries with multiple joins. When you change the join order, the shape of the execution plan may change. I guess that this might by the same issue. Try to check the estimated execution plan for both options to see whether they vary...

When the you place the problematic predicate at the end of the WHERE clause. The execution plan is different (just Microsoft knows why) and the problematic rows that causes the error are filtered out before the conversion.